# How to find difference in time with current time and the time i mention in column of mysql table?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW()-SOME_COLUMN)) 
FROM ANYTABLE;
```

Trying to find the difference of two time values in hours. Also, I'm trying to find the difference of date which is similar to above sql statement, but I'm getting the error: `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF'`.

Advance thanks to those who likes to reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong syntax for `timediff()`. You should use

```
SELECT  HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), SOME_COLUMN)) FROM ANYTABLE;
```

The reference for `TIMEDIFF()` is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

You'll also find reference for `DATEDIFF()` on the same page. The MySQL on-line manual has much information of this type. It should be your first point of reference.